# post comment for an url programmatically in facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Is there a way to post a comment for a given url programmatically in facebook?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do that by simply passing a variable in a url, but you may be interested to learn more from their [developer section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/). For [open graph](http://ogp.me/), I see on the Facebook Developer site that you can only implement LIKES but not comments.

Comment: no am wondering something like this https://graph.facebook.com/1538292028372/comments
      ?message=test+comment&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: For open graph, I see on the Facebook Developer site that you can only implement [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/) but not comments.